# How do i get rid of a trailing $ when using vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

A `$` shows up at the end of every line when I'm using vim and I'm not able to figure out what in my vimrc is causing this. Heres a picture and my entire vimrc below it. What could it be?

[image]

```
set listchars=tab:>-,eol:$,trail:-,precedes:<,extends:>
```

Edited above to remove the irrelevant lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

`set listchars=tab:>-,eol:$,trail:-,precedes:<,extends:>`

is denoting the end-of-line and trailing whitespace with `$` and `-`. Comment the line out with `"` or remove the `eol` portion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether you actually want "list" mode for some reason. I usually only use it when needed and normally have it turned off.

I would change

```
set list
```

To

```
set nolist
```

I expect to see $ at end of line when using list-mode in vi family editors.